# Use same method for inertia response and json response Laravel Jetstream

Tags: php, json, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have been using Laravel powered API and VueJS powered frontend, two separate projects for single page application. Now I want to switch to Laravel Jetstream with Inertia.js as I can create SPA in a single project. Here is an example how inertia works-

```
class UsersController extends Controller

{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::active()
            ->orderByName()
            ->get(['id', 'name', 'email']);

        return Inertia::render('Users', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now we can define `Route::get('users',['UserController::class','index']);` and get user list going to `localhost:8000/users` and see the user list in the web page.

My question is, can I use the same controller and method for API response to use in Mobile App?

I have to build web application and mobile application with same features. For web, I need inertia response and for mobile app, I need json response.  For showing the user list in Laravel project, I can use the code above. But how do I return the same response as JSON like `return response($users);` for mobile application? I can create API routes in `api.php` and make separate controller or method or add condition for API or Inertia response, but I think there might be a better way to handle both Inertia and JSON response using same controller and method.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can totally do that by checking wether or not request wants a json response. Something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::active()
        ->orderByName()
        ->get(['id', 'name', 'email']);

    if (request()->wantsJson()) {
        return $users;
    }

    return Inertia::render('Users', [
        'users' => $users
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I would, indeed, go for ```expectsJson()``` instead of ```wantsJson()``` to cover also ajax requests

Comment: Yes we can do this. But we need to return two response conditionally for each method. It would be better if we can do some configuration in one place and all the response are automatically handled whether it should be Inertia response or json response.

Comment: Is there a laravel 9 equivalent of this?

Answer (score 2):

Being honest here, [partial reloads](https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads) doesn't always cut it. The reason I'm not a big fan is because most things I personally work with are `Promise` based. With [partial reloads](https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads), you would be using a callback. I'll show both ways you can do it since recently this has piqued my interest.

If you want to go about doing it yourself via axios for example:

```
<script>
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

const { version } = usePage();

export default {
    name: 'Users',
    props: {
        users: Object,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            userObj: [],
            loading: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        customReload() {
            this.loading = true;

            this.axios.get('/users', {
                headers: {
                    'X-Inertia': true,
                    'X-Inertia-Partial-Component': 'Users',
                    'X-Inertia-Partial-Data': 'users',
                    'X-Inertia-Version': version.value,
                }
            }).then(({data}) => {
                console.log(data.props.users);
                this.userObj = data.props.users;
            })
            .catch(console.error)
            .then(() => {
                this.loading = false;
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Read more about this titled [The protocol](https://inertiajs.com/the-protocol) in the inertia docs that explain the header data used and what it's for.

#### Pros

- Access ANY inertia render endpoint and get it's props
- You can access the data and manipulate it however you like
- Props are untainted(if you'd like to reference to a previous version)

#### Cons

- Does not update props
- Adds more code complexity
- Storing multiple objects isn't the best use of ram

Now this other approach, we can look into [partial reloads](https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads).
You can call a `partial reload` by calling `this.$inertia.reload({ only: ['PROP_NAME_HERE'] })`, but this isn't all the parameters you can insert.

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Users',
    props: {
        users: Object,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        partialReload() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.$inertia.reload({
                only: ['users'],
                onSuccess() {
                    // Print new props!
                    console.log(this.users);
                },
                onBefore(PendingVisit) {},
                onError(Errors) {},
                onStart() {},
                onProgress() {},
                onComplete() {},
                onAbort() {},
                onCancel() {},
                onFinish(ActiveVisit) {
                    this.loading = false;
                },
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

#### Pros

- Refresh data in props as per documentation
- Less memory overhead

#### Con

- (bias)Callbacks

I do certainly see a point where both of these can be used. Storing the data you get from your custom axios call, may not be necessary, you could be using it for a small object prop. But point is, the option is yours!