# Is it possible to render only data without a view in Laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, eloquent, inertiajs

In my case, I need to be able to send an `Inertia` or `JSON` response via a controller which will be fetched by the component.

I have a sheet without a url which opens on top of a page and I want to be able to do a `Get` on my `web` route to retrieve the data.

I tried this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Data\OperatorMarkerData;
use App\Models\Marker;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class MarkerController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Marker $marker)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'marker' => Inertia::lazy(OperatorMarkerData::from($marker)),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I receive this

```
All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received.
```

In my sheet I use router from Inerta like this :

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReportMarkerSheet from './ReportMarkerSheet';
import ValidationMarkerSheet from './ValidationMarkerSheet';
import { MarkerData } from '@/types/generated';
import { router } from '@inertiajs/react';

type MarkerSheetProps = {
  markerId: number | null;
  operationId: number;
  isOpen: boolean;
  onOpenChange: () => void;
  tab: string;
};

export default function MarkerSheet({ markerId, operationId, isOpen, onOpenChange, tab }: MarkerSheetProps) {
  const [marker, setMarker] = useState<MarkerData>();

  const fetchMarker = async () => {
    if (markerId) {
      try {
        const test = router.get(route('markers.show', markerId));
        console.log(test);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMarker();
  }, [markerId]);

  return (
    <>
      {tab === 'validation' ? (
        <ValidationMarkerSheet
          markerId={markerId}
          operationId={operationId}
          open={isOpen}
          onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
        />
      ) : (
        <ReportMarkerSheet markerId={markerId} operationId={operationId} open={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

I d'like use inertia to avoid having to create API or other solution if it's possible. I don't want use shared data from Handle Inertia too.

Thank you in advanced

Is it explained in my question

Comment: Why would you not return an `Inertia` response from Laravel???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use same method for inertia response and json response Laravel Jetstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384703/use-same-method-for-inertia-response-and-json-response-laravel-jetstream)

Comment: @miken32 

I use Inertia::render but in this case, I have to fetch json from any view without rendering one.

Thanks for the link, I didn't know about `wantsJson()`.

The solution is to create a controller at the root which returns Json, all you have to do is fetch the data on the client side.

My approach was to avoid creating an API and to keep Laravel's native behaviour. Thanks to this solution, I don't have to set any tokens. 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution found is :

Create a controller at the root who return JSON

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Data\OperatorMarkerData;
use App\Models\Marker;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class MarkerController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Marker $marker): JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json(OperatorMarkerData::from($marker));
    }
}
```

And use fetch to client side :

```js
const fetchMarker = async () => {
    if (markerId) {
      try {
        const marker = await fetch(`/markers/${markerId}`).then(response => response.json());
        setMarker(marker);
        setIsLoading(true);
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Un problème est survenu');
      }
    }
  };
```

Thank you for your help